# Breaking out of a loop

Tags: java, loops, break

Im trying to break out of a loop, I just want to keep entering numbers until I enter 0, this is what I have but I can't seem to break it.

```
import javabook.*;

class loop {

    public static void main (String [] args) {

        MainWindow mWin = new MainWindow();
        InputBox iBox = new InputBox(mWin);

        int numbers = iBox.getInteger("");

        while (numbers > 0) {
            if (numbers > 0) {
                iBox.getInteger("EnterNumber");
            } else if (numbers == 0) {
                break;
            }
        }

    }

}
```

Comment: Indent your program properly and you should spot the mistake.

Comment: You never set `numbers` to anything again.

Comment: `numbers` is not being updated in the while loop

Comment: Also: note that in java, there is a strong convention that class names start with capital letter, so it will be a good idea to rename your class to Loop, for instance.

Comment: (Also, the `if (numbers > 0)` is redundant; if the loop body is entered, it's greater than zero.)

Comment: the "numbers" is the user input, I just want it to keep looping until I enter 0

Comment: Useless *break*. `else if (numbers == 0){ break; }` is superfluous because the very same while condition will exit if numbers is 0. The other if is also superfluous.

Answer (score 9):

Looks like you need to reassign numbers to the result of `iBox.getInteger()`.

Try changing

```
iBox.getInteger("EnterNumber");
```

to

```
numbers = iBox.getInteger("EnterNumber");
```

Comment: Wow. Catching a typo gets you four upvotes. Make that five. :)

Answer (score 2):

You set the  value of numbers once. When it is initialized, but you never assign another value to it.
I think that this should work, but I have not tested it.

```
import javabook.*;
 class loop{
  public static void main (String [] args){

 MainWindow mWin = new MainWindow();
 InputBox iBox = new InputBox(mWin);

 int numbers = -1;

 while(numbers != 0){
    numbers = iBox.getInteger("EnterNumber");
}
}
```

}

Answer (score 2):

Try `do-while`:

```
int number;

do {
    number = iBox.getInteger("Enter number: ");
} while (number > 0);
```

Answer (score 1):

If you step through your code in a debugger, you would see you are not changing `numbers` inside your while loop, so it will never exit.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you should try this:

```
numbers = iBox.getInteger("EnterNumber");
```

Answer (score 1):

Follow the suggestions, you will end up with this:

```
while (numbers > 0)
{
    numbers = iBox.getInteger("EnterNumber");
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Useless break.

```
else if (numbers == 0){ break; }
```

is superfluous because the very same while condition will exit if numbers is 0. The other *if* is also superfluous. You can do the same thing with

```
while(numbers > 0){  
    iBox.getInteger("EnterNumber"); 
}
```

Just keep in mind this is an infinite loop since *numbers* will never change.

PS: get a good programming book/tutorial